# How do I Implement MaterialLetterIcon library to my contacts picker?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-imageview, android-viewholder

I've been trying to figure out how to use the library [MaterialLetterIcon](https://github.com/IvBaranov/MaterialLetterIcon) for a while now with no success. I have a custom listview with each item using the image below. An imageview that is selected. This xml file is called da_item.xml

[image]

Currently, the imageview(@+id/contactImage) does nothing. Here is my List populator.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NumberView);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.NameView, holder.text);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.NumberView, holder.number);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox, holder.checkbox);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(!holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                }
            });
            holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(!holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                }
            });
            holder.number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(!holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.number.setText(list.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }
```

I understand how to to add the library, but I am not sure at all how to actually use it. Any suggestions or other libraries to do the same thing would be appreciated too!

Comment: The library's GitHub repo has a README with a "Usage" section, describing how to use the library. Have you read it? What is the specific thing you don't understand about using it? If you feel that the integration steps are unclear - file an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MaterialLetterIcon](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/10/listview-with-letter-in-icon-like-gmail.html) like this way,this is exactly what you looking for

```
ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
        // generate random color
        int color = generator.getColor(getItem(position));
        //int color = generator.getRandomColor();

        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()


                .buildRound(firstLetter, color); // radius in px
```

For more Check [ListViewWithLetterIcon](https://github.com/DevExchanges/ListViewWithLetterIcon)